# Geometric foundation of the Grothendieck polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, schubert-calculus

Grothendieck polynomials were firstly defined in

> Alain Lascoux and Marcel-Paul Sch¨utzenberger. Structure de Hopf de l’anneau de cohomologie et de l’anneau de Grothendieck d’une vari´et´e de drapeaux. C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris S´er. I Math., 295(11):629–633, 1982.

to be a computation of K-theory of flag manifold. It is in French and hard to get access. And as far as I saw, I did not find out any reference explaining the geometric meaning in a precise way.

For this I have a series of questions. Let me use $G/B$ to stand for the flag manifolds.

---

**Firstly, how to define the Schubert cells in $K(G/B)$? Are the following two definitions the same?**

- If one prefers to work in algebraic K-theory, then we can simply define it to be the push forward of $\mathcal{O}_{Bw_0wB/B}$ over $G/B$.
- If one insists to use the topological one, then I believe the only way to define it is by the Atiyah–Hirzebruch spectral sequence. Since $E^{pq}_2 = H^p(G/B;K^q(pt))$ has only even dimensions, so it collapses, and we can define the Schubert cells to be the corresponding Schubert cells in $H^{2k}(G/B;K^{-2k}(pt))$.
- Due to some big theorem (for example, projective bundle theorem), the algebraic K-group coincides with topological K-group in our case. Are these two definitions the same?

---

**Secondly, what is the meaning for the indeterminants $x_1,\ldots,x_n$?**

Actually, in Lascoux and Sch¨utzenberger exposition

> Symmetry and flag manifolds, Invariant theory, Springer, 1983, pp. 118–144.

The $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are exchanged from $L_1,\ldots,L_n$ by $x_i=1-L_i^{-1}$. I guess this $L_i$ is the line bundle $G\times_B \mathbb{C}$ with $B$ acts over $\mathbb{C}$ by the $i$-th index over diagonal.

---

**Thirdly, how to compute the isobaric Demazure operators?**

Firstly, how to define push forward in topological sense is a little hard. But one still can do so by Atiyah–Hirzebruch spectral sequence or some variantion of Thom isomorphism.

I think one can compute the isobaric Demazure operators $\pi_i$ for general $\mathbb{C}P^1$ bundle.
This may not be very hard.
But the problem is why $\pi_i \Sigma_w=\begin{cases}\Sigma_{s_iw},&\ell(w)=\ell(s_iw)+1\\0,& \ell(w)=\ell(s_iw)-1. \end{cases}$

---

**Lastly, why the topmost element is presented by $x_1^{n-1}\cdots x_{n-1}$?**

Definitely, there are a lot of choices of the presentitve, but why it is $\bmod \mathbb{Z}[x]^W_+$?
In cohomology case, we can compute taking advantage of dimension, but in K-theory case $\pi_i$ does not reduce dimensions.

By the way, I believe that one can get this from the equivariant case, by the localization theorem. But I am not sure that the equivariant topology was wildly used that time. Especially, the algebraic equivairant K-theory is established in 1983 by Thomason.

---

Generally, I suspect that the Chern character is mainly used, but I did not figure out how Chern character reflects the cell structures.

Answer (score 3):

First, one can resolve the Schubert varieties using Bott-Samelson manifolds, and discover that any two resolutions give the same class upon pushforward. (This good situation ends with K-theory, i.e. is not true for e.g. cobordism.)

Second, the $x_i$ are hard to interpret geometrically on $G/B$. It's much easier if you note $K(GL_n/B) = K_B(GL_n) = K_T(GL_n) \leftarrow K_T(Mat_n)$ where $x_i$ becomes the class of each coordinate hyperplane $m_{ji}=0$ (any $j$).

Third, maybe I'm confusing Demazure vs. isobaric Demazure but the two cases I'm used to are $\Sigma_{w s_i}$ vs. $\Sigma_w$ (no $0$, and, $s_i$ on the other side than you have).

Fourth becomes easy if you say that the class of a point in $GL_n/B$ comes from the class of the lower triangular matrices in $Mat_n$, using the identifications above.